# hide the calendar popup of <input type="date"> in Firefox

Tags: javascript, date, firefox

In Firefox, `input type="date"` brings a calendar popup on click.
In Chrome, we can use `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` to hide the down arrow button showing the calendar. Apart from preventing the default behavior on click, I haven't found a -moz pseudo-element equivalent to hide the calendar. I don't want to use `type='text'` either.

Is there any way to hide this popup calendar in Firefox?

Comment: I'm looking for this right now and found no answer. How'd you end up solving it? I'll post something here if I'm able to come up with something

Comment: I haven't found a way to hide it and solved my issue in a completely different way. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, same here. Apparently there is no pseudo element in firefox. Shame!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no event link to your input you can do :

```
$('#your-input').on('click', function(){
    return false;
});
```